# how can I restrict the output of edge-based traffic to the given list of edge ids in SUMO

Tags: sumo

when I restrict the output of edge-based traffic to the given list of edge ids in SUMO by restricting the additional file like
`<edgeData id="edges" file="XX.edge.xml" freq ="5" edges="123456"/>`.
And then I open the sumo.config file in sumo-gui,it shows
"unknown edge "123456" in edgeData definition 'edges'.
So how can I restrict the output to the given list of edge ids correctly?

I have no ideas.I really need someone to help me!Thany you!

Comment: the additional file is " <edgeData id="edges" file="XX.edge.xml" freq ="5" edges="123456" />"

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct, sumo just complains that the edge "123456" is not known, so you should should double check whether an edge with that id is really in the network.